# What is the linear system to an invertible sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I know we can define the linear system to a divisor. But how to define the linear system of an invertible sheaf. I meet this in the following context.

Let $X$ be a Noetherian scheme and $L$ be a line bundle on it. Then, the author talks about the linear system $|L|$.

1. I think the language of linear system is only defined for smooth projective $k$-varieties. But why could we use linear system in this case?
2. Is there any general corresponding between (class of) divisors and (class of) invertible sheaves on a scheme?
3. In general, could we define a linear system or a complete linear system for an invertible sheaf on a scheme?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The answer to your question (2) is yes, and is the reason we can do all of this. This is Proposition II 7.7 of Hartshorne. The point is that for any global section $s \in H^0(X, L)$ we can form the divisor of zeroes $(s)_0$ and this gives a correspondance between linear equivalence classes of divisors and isomorphism classes of line bundles.

Comment: You might see this as the correspondance between $\operatorname{CaCl}(X)$, $\operatorname{Div}(X)$, and $\operatorname{Pic}(X)$ when $X$ is "nice".

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It's really helpful. But it seems that $CaCl(X) = Pic(X)$ holds only for integral schemes. Why he can do the same thing also for a general Noetherian scheme?

Comment: I go through the proof of proposition 7.7. It seems that (a)(b) holds for arbitrary integral schemes. Statement (c) holds for projective variety over algebraically closed fields. But why Harteshorne assumes $X$ to be nonsingular? I'm not sure but it seems that he never use this assumption in the proof.

Comment: You can see in the discussion preceding the Proposition that Hartshorne wishes for the notions of Cartier and Weil divisors to coincide - this only happens when $X$ is a non-singular projective variety over and alg. closed field.

Comment: To your first question I was motivating the definition of a linear system as $(H^0(X, L) - \{0\})/k^{\times}$ which can be seen below this proposition. Notice that in this language we can introduce linear systems without ever referring to divisors.

Comment: Does that mean if we only work with Cartier divisors, the proposition still holds for schemes not necessarily nonsingular?